# Calculate a list of possible int sequences with length K

Tags: java, sequences

Let's say I can have a sequence of integers, of length K. Each of those values can be any int from 1 to N. How can I calculate a list of ALL possible sequences that follow this pattern? I know that's a lot, N^K, but I plan on dealing with smaller numbers.

**EDIT:** 
In Java, but pseudo-code is fine

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=all%20permutations%20digits%20java

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm thinking of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated to be 1 to N, instead of 0 to N-1**

Think of it as incrementing a base-N number of K digits. This makes for a simple non-recursive implementation:

```
int[] seq = new int[K];
Arrays.fill(seq, 1);
OUTER: while (true) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(seq));
    for (int i = K - 1; true; i--) {
        int v = seq[i] + 1;
        if (v <= N) {
            seq[i] = v;
            break;
        }
        if (i == 0)
            break OUTER;
        seq[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

E.g. for K = 2 and N = 3:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
```

Comment: What if the values range from 1 to N instead of 0 to N - 1?

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in certain areas of computer science.  A good reference for solutions to these types of problems is *The Art of Computer Programming* by Donald Knuth.  He addresses this particular problem of generating all n-tuples in Section 7.2.1.1 of the book.  A draft (in PDF form) of the portion of the book that contains this section can be found [here](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc2a.pdf).

There are several solutions discussed in the book, and which solution is best may depend on your circumstances.  The answer I give here corresponds to Knuth's first solution.  He gives it in more general form than your specific question, so I'll adapt it to specifically what you asked.  I switch your `n` and `k` around, so that `n` is the length of the sequence and `k` is the largest integer you want to use, and rather than storing all of the n-tuples, I use a visitor pattern that will visit each n-tuple.  You could implement the visitor to store a copy of each visited n-tuple if you want to store all of them.

I have not tested this, but even if there are some bugs in it, you will get the idea, I think.

```
public interface Visitor {
    void visit(int[] nTuple);
}

public void generateAndVisitNTuples(int n, int k, Visitor v) {
    int[] nTuple = new int[n];
    // initialize each digit to one
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        nTuple[i] = 1;
    }
    while (true) {
        v.visit(nTuple);
        int j = n - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && nTuple[j] == k) {
            // this is a digit j that is at the maximum, so reset it to 1
            nTuple[j] = 1
            --j;
        }
        if (j < 0) {
            // all digits j were at maximum, so all n-tuples have been visited
            break;
        }
        // this digit j is not yet at its maximum, so increase it
        ++nTuple[j];
    }
}
```

You might want to implement some bounds to ensure that that n and k passed into the method are in the proper range.